# Script to copy files and folders based on the latest backup

Tags: robocopy

I have backups running everyday on a system and that system DB itself is not backed up, which I would be changing it very soon to move to the production server. But, for temporary I am looking for a Robocopy script that would move all files and folders from that server to network location based on the last date it was backed up.

I retain 5 days worth of backup on the server itself and it automatically gets deleted. The way it saves the backup file is shown in the format below. So, I want it to actually ready the latest date like 6/10/2019 was the last good backup which was yesterday night and then probably I want to run this at around 2 am or something to copy it to the network so it is saved there and it is safe incase this system crashes.

```
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_10_2019_23_00



robocopy \\Server\D$\ME\SD\backuplocation\backupfolder and files

\\network file share\ME\ME Backups Daily\ Copy /e
```

I am not sure how to make sure that the latest backup folder is being backed up as it has 5 days worth of backup folders in that location.

So, I want it to pick up the first one or the top one which is the latest one and copy it. Not move it.

```
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_10_2019_23_00
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_09_2019_23_00
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_08_2019_23_00
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_07_2019_23_00
backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_06_06_2019_23_00
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop will put the name of the newest folder into the variable `newest`, assuming that the newest folder is the one which was last written to:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad/od/tw backup_mssql_10017_fullbackup_*') do @set newest=%%a
```

Then, use `%newest` in your robocopy command.

Options used:
`/b`   name only
`/ad`   folders only
`/od`   order by date, ascending
`/tw`   use last modified timestamp (not last accessed or created)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and get back.